# Can we weld two dissimilar metals without using LASER welding?

Tags: laser

It is said that one of the many advantages of LASER welding over ordinary welding is that it can be used to weld two dissimilar metals, what problems do we face while welding two dissimilar metals by ordinary methods?

Comment: You just need to heat the two metals to above their melting points without allowing anything chemical to happen to them.
Normally means heating them quickly without a flame - see friction welding

Comment: I think this is more engineering than physics

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_beam_welding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welding dissimilar metals without lasers is done all the time. That's how 
[thermocouples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple#Circuit_construction) are made. The process in this case is spot welding. You just clamp two pieces of metal together and put a high-enough current pulse through them. The metals need to be clean, of course, and you want to make sure they won't catch fire, but that's true of any welding process. Of course, spot welding is limited to fairly small weld areas.

For larger welds, any form of arc welding will potentially work, although some metals are harder to work with than others. For arc welding, the weld itself is provided by a bead of some material which fuses with the pieces being welded, and the more dissimilar the metals the harder it is to find a bead material which will work well. The problem is usually not so much getting the metals to fuse as it is that the resulting interface can be unacceptably weak or brittle.

Another technique (not for the faint of heart and definitely a specialty approach) is [explosion welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosion_welding) which is exactly what it sounds like. It has the advantage that it doesn't require a bead material like arc welding does. While I don't have a link, I recall seeing an article many years ago (like 30 to 40) which proposed bonding wire to metal pads by means of a thin layer of explosive on the top of the wire, with the explosive initiated by a laser pulse. Since I never again saw the technique proposed or even discussed, this probably wasn't a very practical idea.